# Базы данных и MVC. Как правильно реализовать модели с отношением "один ко многим"

Tags: база-данных, mvc, data-mapper

Добрый день!

К примеру, есть 2 сущности:

1. User - пользователь с полями:

   - Id
   - Name
   - Articles (список статей)
2. Article - статья сайта с полями:

   - Id
   - Title
   - Content

С точки зрения ООП лучше всего пользователю хранить список его статей, но с точки зрения баз данных - у таблицы `article` нужно добавить foreign key `idUser`, в котором будет храниться id владельца данной статьи, поэтому, как я понимаю, второй способ правильный.

Теперь сам **вопрос**: В веб-приложении, разработанному по паттерну MVC, есть модели `User` и `Article`. В базе данных есть соответствующие таблицы. При маппинге таблиц в модели у класса `Article` будет поле (свойство) `idUser`. Как реализовать класс `User так`, чтобы он в случае необходимости мог получить список своих статей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

зачем дублировать список статей юзера в базе юзера 
у вас же есть в списке статеи `id` автора статьи, может проще 
добавить в модель `Article` поля
`User As User`
`UserId As Integer`
и выводить потом списком статьи `Userа` по `UserId` из базы `Article`

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что так можно сделать! Просто обычно если мы пишем на объектно-ориентированном языке программирования, то мы, к примеру, когда создаем класс `Driver`, то мы ему пишем обычно свойство "List<Cars>", а не наоборот. Поэтому я и решил спросить. И получается, что когда мы будем вызывать у модели `User` метод GetAllArticles, то мы будем обращаться к таблице `Article`, я правильно понял?

Comment: да все правильно , тогда может это поможет https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.7.php

Comment: Отлично, это именно то, что я хотел узнать, спасибо!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста